# how do I get a string between two specific characters in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, string

```
string test = "item_id - description (moreInfo)"
```

I want to grab the description.

test will always start with "item_id - "

test will always end with " (xxx)"

test could have anything in the description, like space, dashes, etc.

So basically I need to capture the string after the first " - " UNTIL the last " ("

I'm having a hard time with this.

Comment: What's the problem with string.IndexOf and string.LastIndexOf? Pretty simple

Comment: what for cases like `item_id - description (vghvhj) (moreInfo)`, `item_id - description (more((((Info)`?

Comment: regex class:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void WithRegex(string test)
    {
        string extracted = new Regex(@"- ?(.*) ?\([^\(]+$").Match(test).Groups[1].Value;
        Console.WriteLine("Extracted: {0}", extracted);
    }

    public static void WithoutRegex(string test)
    {
        string extracted = test.Substring(test.IndexOf("-") + 1, test.LastIndexOf("(") - test.IndexOf("-") - 1).Trim();
        Console.WriteLine("Extracted: {0}", extracted);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        string test = "item_id - description (something else) !onuth - hi you (moreInfo)";
        WithRegex(test);
        WithoutRegex(test);
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Extracted: description (something else) !onuth - hi you
Extracted: description (something else) !onuth - hi you
```

Comment: sorry, should have been more clear. the item_id will be an ID but it'll be different ... 3292, 32804, 333, 1133, etc same with the the (moreinfo) part

Comment: It doesn't matter, it'll match.

Comment: worked beautifully. thank you sir. i can accept your answer in 3 mins.

Comment: You are most welcome, @Rj. The non-regex will be faster and use less memory. Don't forget to do error handling. Substring will return -1 if the character we're searching for isn't found.

Comment: I would still go fo the regex. It is realy fast and considered good code when dealing with such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here this should get you started on the right track:

```
var reg = new Regex(@"^item_id - (.+) \(moreInfo\)$");
string test = "item_id - description (moreInfo)";
var match = reg.Match(test);

if(match.Success)
{
    if(match.Groups.Count > 1)
    {
        var group = match.Groups[1];
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(group.Value); // prints your description....
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, should have been more clear. the item_id will be an ID but it'll be different ... 3292, 32804, 333, 1133, etc same with the the (moreinfo) part

Comment: @Rj. -- Ah, yes, that woulda been helpful up front.

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "1234 - description (moreInfo)";
string pattern = "\\d+\\s*-([^\\(]+)";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

Match match = rgx.Match(input);

if (match.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/ti2E6B)**

Comment: sorry, should have been more clear. the item_id will be an ID but it'll be different ... 3292, 32804, 333, 1133, etc

Comment: I think `item_id` is not a constant, it can be a number or anything else.

Comment: @Rj. updated..do you want your string ending with `(moreInfo)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a combination of `IndexOf` and `LastIndexOf` using `Substring`

`test.Substring(test.IndexOf("- ") + 2, test.LastIndexOf("(") - (test.IndexOf("- ") + 2))`;

Answer (score 0):

Without using Regex:

```
public void SelectPartOfString()
{
    string test = "item_id - description (moreInfo)";
    int beginIndex = test.IndexOf("-") + 1; //char immediately after `-`
    int endIndex = test.LastIndexOf("(") - 1; //char immediately before last `(`

    string subString = test.Substring(beginIndex, (endIndex - beginIndex)).Trim(' '); //remove leading/trailing spaces

    Console.WriteLine(subString);
}
```